# How can I pass a state from component A to B if they are not connected?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm practicing react router. This is my App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>

      <Nav/>

      <Switch>
        <Route path = "/" exact component = {Home}/>
        <Route path = "/shop" exact component = {Shop} />
        <Route path = "/cart" component = {Cart}/>

      </Switch>

    </Router>
  );
}
```

In **Shop** component, I have a state:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
```

How could **Cart** (and **Nav**) component have access to it?

Comment: You need to use react context for this, or redux or mobx.

Comment: Or give the state from your main component down as props to your routes using the render  function

Comment: Put the state in the App components and share the state via props

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the Context API ([see here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)) or React Redux ([see here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)). Both are good for state management. Context would be better for smaller projects, while Redux for bigger ones.